# POST form does not work when adding JS scripts in VIEWS

Tags: javascript, java, playframework

I have some trouble with My POST FORM ACTIONS once I added some javascripts such as : datepicker...etc

Any idea please?
By he way, Javascripts has no relation with the Result method checkbox() in controller.....I do not know why there are conflicts between controller and js scripts!!!

[image]

1- View Template Code ( When I put Javascript inside comments My method Result checkbox in java code works fine )

Here is My method Result checkbox ()

```
public Result checkbox() {


      String[] postAction = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("action");

      String action = postAction[0];

      if (postAction == null || postAction.length == 0) 
      {return badRequest("Veuillez selectionner une Action Valide");} 

      else
      {  

          String[] computers = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("chkItems"); 


          if (computers != null && ("PDF Report".equals(action) || "HTML Report".equals(action) || "XLS Report".equals(action) || "New Edit".equals(action) || "JsonList".equals(action))  ) 
          {
              String ids = ListUtils.mkString(computers, s -> "" + s, ";");
              Logger.info("ids Selected are : "+ids);

              switch (action) 
              {

                   case     "PDF Report"       : return GenerateReport(ids,"pdf");
                   case     "XLS Report"       : return GenerateReport(ids,"xls");
                   case     "HTML Report"      : return GenerateReport(ids,"html");
                   case     "New Edit"         : return EditNames(ids,"Edit From Action");                       
                   default                     : return ok("default switch : Action <<"+action+">> avec Parametres Error>>"); 
              } 
          }

          else if (computers == null && ("PDF Report".equals(action) || "HTML Report".equals(action) || "XLS Report".equals(action) || "New Edit".equals(action) || "JsonList".equals(action))  ) 
          {
           return ok("Cette Action necessite au moins un parametre d'entré");     
          } 


          else
          {
              switch (action) 
              {


                   case     "Add New"             : return Results.redirect(routes.Computers.create());
                   case     "Send Simple Mail"    : return SendSimpleEmail();
                   case     "Send Complex Mail"   : return SendComplexEmail();
                   case     "Open IMG File"       : return OpenIMGfile("./public/images/wall.jpg");
                default                           : return ok("default switch : Action <<"+action+">> sans Parametres Error>>"); 
              } 

          }  



      }}







@scripts = { 
         <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/computers/delete.js")"></script>
         <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/computers/put.js")"></script>
         <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/computers/dt_computers.js")"></script>                                     
       }
```

@main(user, scripts) {

}

Comment: could you add the code here? I cant see images

Comment: Please show the code where you added those checkboxes. Also check the browser developer console if there is any JavaScript error

Comment: Hi,
I am not using JAVASCRIPT for launching a java Action..
Javascript are added to view template for something else, and, when i make those scripts as comment, My request.body took correctly checkbox selected and the action method ( Result checkbox() ) is functional
I will post my codes in few moments..

Comment: Hello,

ntahoang,
you are right, one of the scripts JS causes the problem :
that one :

    
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/computers/dt_computers.js")">



Could you please tell me why checkboxes are null in the : 

    String[] computers = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("chkItems");

Comment: Throwing exception when `postAction == null` is not correct, because when checkbox is unchecked, nothing is sent in POST request, you must handle this as a business case, not throwing bad request exception.

Comment: Hello ntahoang,
When I put a normal HTML TABLE, i can easily get checkbox selected from postAction the problem is when i change HTML TABLE to DATATABLE?
by the way postAction is not null and return correctly the name from the button form


String[] computers = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("chkItems");   == NULL ( datatable only)

Comment: I really cannot understand what you meant for HTML TABLE and DATA TABLE :(. I wanted to know how checkboxes are built in browser, are they standard HTML checkboxes or generated by some plugin/framework

Comment: Can I send you my little Sample Example ?
I can not add comments with codes here im really sorry

Comment: Yes, why not, please send it to ntahoang(at)gmail(dot)com